# find the Integer value after a string from a file

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I want to get the integer value after a specific string from a file and sort all the integers.
Ex - 
I have a file with thousands of lines with string weight,

```
-weight 100
-weight 200
-weight 20
```

I want to get all the integer values in sorted order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are searching for the longest string of numbers that is the last thing on the line, you can just use `grep`:

```
$ grep -oP '\d+\s*$' file 
100
200
20
```

The `-o` tells `grep` to only print the matching portion of the line and the `-P` enables Perl Compatible Regular Expressions. PCREs let us use `\d+` for "one or more digits" and `\s*` for "0 or more whitespace characters". So, all together, that command will print the longest stretch of numbers found at the end of the line.

If you need them sorted, just pass through `sort`:

```
$ grep -oP '\d+\s*$' file | sort -n
20
100
200
```

If, instead, you need to anchor your pattern using a specific string, use:

```
$ grep -oP -- '-weight\s+\K\d+' file | sort -n
20
100
200
```

The `\K` tells `grep` not to include anything matched up to this point, so the command above will only print the longest stretch of numbers after the `-weight` and 0 or more spaces.

Note that if you want to also include negative numbers or decimals, you will need:

```
grep -oP -- '-weight\s+\K[0-9,-]+' file | sort -n
```

For example:

```
$ cat file 
-weight 100
-weight 200
-weight 20
-weight -29
-weight -32.4

$ grep -oP -- '-weight\s+\K[0-9,-]+' file | sort -n
-32
-29
20
100
200
```

Comment: i had to remove \K to print the output, otherwise there was'nt any output on the screen.

Comment: @asad_nitp that doesn't make sense, without the `\K` you would be getting the whole line.

Answer (score 3):

Try this sed command:

```
sed -E 's/^.*weight\s([[:digit:]]*).*/\1/' sort.txt  | sort -n
```

Or

```
sed -E 's/.*weight\s([0-9]*).*/\1/' sort.txt | sort -n
```

Test case:

```
-weight 100 
-weight 200 
-weight 20
```

Results:

```
20
100 
200
```

**Note:- You didn't give a good test case so I assumed mine.**

Info:

- `^.*weight\s([[:digit:]])`: Read each line and capture the numbers after the word "weight" with the "space" following.
- `| sort -n`: Pipe the output into the sort command and sort by numeric value.

Comment: For the input shown, something like `sed 's/[^0-9]*//'` would be sufficient I think

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
cut -d ' ' -f2 inputfile|sort -n
```

`-d ' '` - set delimiter to space
`-f2` - get second column
`sort -n` - sort result as numbers
Test result:

```
20
100
200
```

Comment: this works when there are only two columns, so i grep'd the -weight and value and then sorted using this method.

Comment: With a correct example answer will be different, so you will not need to grep. Provide an example then ping me, and I will change the answer.